# Using php conditional statement to print image with echo

Tags: php, conditional-statements

Hey I'm trying to use php to display an image for each day of the week. I've used the date("D") function to do this but my code doesn't seem to be working. Can someone please take a quick look at it?

```
<?php
$today = date("D");

if ($today == "Sun")
    echo "Today is Sunday" <img src = 'C:\Users\A1\Documents\2016\Semester 2\ISYS 227\Tutorials\images\sun.jpg'/>;
    elseif ($today == "Mon")
        echo "Today is Monday. <img src = 'C:\Users\A1\Documents\2016\Semester 2\ISYS 227\Tutorials\images\mon.jpg'/>;
    elseif ($today == "Tue")
        echo "Today is Tuesday". <img src = 'C:\Users\A1\Documents\2016\Semester 2\ISYS 227\Tutorials\images\tue.jpg'/>;
    elseif ($today == "Wed")
        echo "Today is Wednesday". <img src = 'C:\Users\A1\Documents\2016\Semester 2\ISYS 227\Tutorials\images\wed.jpg'/>;
    elseif ($today == "Thur")
        echo "Today is Thursday". <img src = 'C:\Users\A1\Documents\2016\Semester 2\ISYS 227\Tutorials\images\thur.jpg'/>';
    elseif ($today == "Fri")
        echo "Today is Friday. <img src = 'C:\Users\A1\Documents\2016\Semester 2\ISYS 227\Tutorials\images\fri.jpg'/>;
    elseif ($today == "Sat")
        echo "Today is Saturday. <img src = 'C:\Users\A1\Documents\2016\Semester 2\ISYS 227\Tutorials\images\sat.jpg'/>;
    else    
    echo "I do not know the day of the week.";

?>
```

Comment: syntax error in your code...use switch instead of if ... use relative path instead of absolute


Example

:
`echo "Today is Sunday <img src = '/images/sun.jpg'/>";`

Comment: And you should use **url** path not **disk** path

Comment: Use multidirectional array and remove all if, you can do this whole things in 3 lines of code, 1. Array like ("Mon"=> "yormon.jpg"....) And check if array key exist and echo img

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because user lake in minimal understaning about pprograming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have closed off your quotes too early

```
echo "Today is Sunday" <img src = ''/>;
```

should be:

```
echo "Today is Sunday <img src = ''/>" ;
```

Removed image source to make it easier to read.

Also, as pointed out in the comments, use relative path.

I have tested this and it works.

Full Code:

```
<?php
$today = date("D");

if ($today == "Sun")
    echo "Today is Sunday <img src = 'images/sun.jpg'/>" ;
    elseif ($today == "Mon")
        echo "Today is Monday. <img src = 'images/mon.png'/>";
    elseif ($today == "Tue")
        echo "Today is Tuesday. <img src = 'images/tue.jpg'/>";
    elseif ($today == "Wed")
        echo "Today is Wednesday. <img src = 'images/wed.jpg'/>";
    elseif ($today == "Thur")
        echo "Today is Thursday. <img src = 'images/thur.jpg'/>";
    elseif ($today == "Fri")
        echo "Today is Friday. <img src = 'images/fri.jpg'/>";
    elseif ($today == "Sat")
        echo "Today is Saturday. <img src = 'images/sat.jpg'/>";
    else    
    echo "I do not know the day of the week.";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could this be what you were attempting to do:

```
<?php
    $today      = date("D");        
    if ($today == "Sun") {
        echo "Today is Sunday. <img src = 'C:\Users\A1\Documents\2016\Semester 2\ISYS 227\Tutorials\images\sun.jpg'/>\n";
    }elseif ($today == "Mon") {
        echo "Today is Monday. <img src = 'C:\Users\A1\Documents\2016\Semester 2\ISYS 227\Tutorials\images\mon.jpg'/>";
    }elseif ($today == "Tue") {
        echo "Today is Tuesday. <img src = 'C:\Users\A1\Documents\2016\Semester 2\ISYS 227\Tutorials\images\tue.jpg'/>";
    }elseif ($today == "Wed"){  
        echo "Today is Wednesday. <img src = 'C:\Users\A1\Documents\2016\Semester 2\ISYS 227\Tutorials\images\wed.jpg'/>";
    }elseif ($today == "Thur") {
        echo "Today is Thursday. <img src = 'C:\Users\A1\Documents\2016\Semester 2\ISYS 227\Tutorials\images\thur.jpg'/>";
    }elseif ($today == "Fri") {
        echo "Today is Friday. <img src = 'C:\Users\A1\Documents\2016\Semester 2\ISYS 227\Tutorials\images\fri.jpg'/>";
    }elseif ($today == "Sat") {
        echo "Today is Saturday. <img src = 'C:\Users\A1\Documents\2016\Semester 2\ISYS 227\Tutorials\images\sat.jpg'/>";
    }else {
        echo "I do not know the day of the week.";
    }
```